# Manipulate "speaker voicer'' in Text-to-Speech C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

I'm working on a Text-to-Speech Application in C#. How to configure its TONE via an C# API? Or, do I need to download a library for that functionality? For example: `Microsoft Sam`'s voice, now I wish to configure a self-define voice too.

Is is possible? Is 'SpeechSynthesizer' one of the key of doing this?

Comment: What kind of tuning do you intend??

Comment: to configure a self-defined voice. Is it possible?

Comment: I dont think that's possible. I have worked on a text to speech app few years ago. I dont exactly remember but you can try Microsoft Speech SDK and that may help you.

Comment: So about 'pitch' tuning? This is possible right? Like I can tune it to become a female or male voice.

Comment: I must say you have to research for this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130935/are-there-any-other-text-to-speech-voices-for-net) on changing the voice.  You cannot manipulate the voice at all using C#, short of telling it what voice to use, if you have more than one installed. You can tweak some features of the voice using [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/), such as pitch and prosody, but these are more subtle changes and do not change the overall voice.  To modify the voice you need to install one compatible with the TTS engine you are using.  These voice packages come with pre-recorded phonemes of the voice that you are interested in.  Some companies, like [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/automotive-products-services/vocalizer-for-automotive/index.htm), will create custom voice for you but this is very expensive.